# How add data in nested relation? I have" Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection" error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I want to add data in relational model

```
public class person
{
    public int id {get;set;}
    public string name {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<phone> Phones {get;set;}
}

public class Phone{
    public int id {get;set;}
    public string Phonenumber {get;set;}
    public int personid {get;set;}
    public virtual person Person {get;set;}             
    public virtual ICollection<phone> Phones {get;set;}
    
    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses {get;set;}
}

public class Address{
    public int id {get;set;}
    public string desc {get;set;}
}
```

when i fill

```
person.Phones[0].Addresses[0].desc= "1";
```

I have this error:

How do I resolve index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection

Comment: "I have this error:" - what error?

Comment: Probably there are no Phones or no Addresses on the Phone at index 0.

Comment: how do fix it code?

Comment: I have phone and then set address for phone